Google Translate widget was not working as expected
We are using the Google Translate widget on our website, supporting two languages: English and Tamil.
We identified a problem with the Google Translate dropdown, which is explained step by step below.
Step 1: The site first loads in the default language, English. After changing to Tamil, it works correctly.
Step 2: After switching back to English, it works fine.
Step 3: When changing back to Tamil, it does not work. Instead, it shows "Select language".


Our Code:
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
574/8, Lakshmi lllam,<br>
    Malligai West Cross Street,<br>
    Malligai Veethi,<br>
    Gomathipuram,<br>
    Madurai - 123456.
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({
pageLanguage: 'en',
includedLanguages: 'en,ta',  // Add the languages you want to include
layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
autoDisplay: false,
}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

Please suggest.
